# Is there a way to serve s3 files directly to the user, with a url that cant be shared?

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, amazon-s3, session

I'm storing some files for a website on S3. Currently, when a user needs a file, I create a signed url (query string authentication) that expires and send that to their browser. However they can then share this url with others before the expiration.

What I want is some sort of authentication that ensures that the url will only work from the authenticated users browser.

I have implemented a way to do this by using my server as a relay between amazon and the user, but would prefer to point the users directly to amazon.

Is there a way to have a session cookie of some sort created in the users browser, and then have amazon expect that session cookie before serving files?

Comment: I'm not sure how s3 works but i think you can create a ticket url, send the number of the ticket to the client, save the key to client browser and make it to be invoked on request

Comment: Didn't find anything on google along those lines...links?

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible with S3 alone, but CloudFront provides this feature. Take a look at this chapter in the documentation: [Using a Signed URL to Serve Private Content](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/PrivateContent.html).

Comment: CloudFront seems to be more of a CDN type service. That isn't really what we need as we wouldn't want our content distributed to edge servers. Also I see it can sign URLs with an IP, which is nice, but still not terribly secure. I think you are right in stating that it cannot be achieved by s3 alone.

Comment: Then the only other solution which will work is routing the data trafic through an EC2 instance which handles the security aspects you mentioned … But to be honest: I think CloudFront + a custom policy statement is the easiest and most (cost) effective way to achiev your plan.

Comment: Thanks so much for the advice. I'm not sure I understand the basics...We give cloudfront access to the bucket, and then sign all cloudfront urls limiting to the ip? Or is there a more robust security from cloudfront? Can you link me to anything about configuring in the way you are suggesting? Thanks, T

Comment: First I would start with this [webinar](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yvCYTDkjMJw&feature=plcp) and then just work your way through the [CloudFront documentation](http://docs.amazonwebservices.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/GettingStarted.html).